# Falla en la validacion de administrador

Tags: php, sql-server, formularios, login, validación

Tengo un problema. Necesito crear un modulo de reportes para una pagina web que ya esta en linea, utilizando php, javascript, y la base de datos esta en sql server: Soy nuevo en esto, ya que en el curso que vi de programacion me enseñaron a manejar MySQL. Lo que tengo planeado en lo basico es crear un login para usuarios y un solo administrador. Ya hice el login, las validaciones para poder entrar a otra pagina diferente, pero el problema es que al ingresar cualquier dato en el formulario el sistema lo deja acceder. Francamente no se que hacer, les pido ayuda para resolver esto.

Este es mi codigo PHP:

```
<?php 

$Administrador = $_POST['AdminName'];
$contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];
if (isset($_POST['btnAdmin'])) {    

    $serverName = "AFTIC004";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"UneteAlParche_BD", "UID"=>"codestack", "PWD"=>"jrdLpWad5ik3rFWatjLQ" );
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if ($conn == true) {
        header("location: VentanaReportesAdminIngresado.html");
    }else{
        echo "Conexión incorrecta. <br>";
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        return false;
    }

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM sisAdministrador WHERE IdAdmin = ?, Nombre = ? AND Password = ? AND IdRol = ";
    $params = array(1, $Administrador,$contrasena,3);
    $resultado= sqlsrv_query($conn, $consulta, $params);

    if ($resultado == false) {
        echo "Consulta erronea. ";
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        return false;
    }else{
        header("location: VentanaReportesAdminIngresado.html");
    }
}
?>
```

Si necesitan alguna informacion extra para ayudarme en mi problema díganmelo. Les pido colaboración

Comment: Creo que el problema es que estás comparando contra `false` en vez de evaluar el número de filas del resultado.

Comment: Por favor, se mas especifico

Comment: En tu linea `if ($resultado == false)` es probable que el valor de `$resultado` no sea false sino algo distinto puesto que no debería regresar un valor booleano.

Comment: Acabo de borrar el false del if pero sigue accediendo ingresando cualquier cosa en el login